# SSIS Rows Being Reduced From Original Amount

Tags: excel, ssis, excel-2010, oledb, dataflowtask

I can't seem to figure this out?

Out of the 28,804 rows I'm extracting from SQL Server to Insert into Excel Data Source I'm being limited to just 10,000 and I'm not sure why. On the Data Flow Task properties I've switched AutoAdjustBufferSize to True and False as I suspect this might be to do with buffer size; it didn't help.

If I limit the actual query to 10000 rows or less no problems but above that the package just hangs but doesn't necessarily fail

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Sometimes the numbers on the data flow lie. Did you check the actual Excel file?

Comment: @Chris. Well, I know that there are 28,804 rows in SQL Server. I've also put a Watch in between the items and I can verify the data. But the execution never completes. It just hovers so no output is generated in Excel. If I change the SQL query in OLE DB Source to Select Top 10000. The execution completes no problem. Very confusing!

Comment: What is the data type of the field you are converting and to what type? Also, I think its not a problem with your source or conversion, its more to do with Excel. How many columns are you loading to the excel destination?

Comment: One option you can experiment is to do the data conversion in SQL Server (e.g., create **view** from your source query and use that as a source) and map your source to the destination directly. From experience, i have seen that using data conversion creates such problems when your data size is big or sometimes related to your pc memory limit.

Comment: What is the warning on the Excel destination telling you? If you use a different destination (flat file, db table, etc) do you still have the same issue?

Comment: I almost never use data conversion object. Try using derived column and casting to the data type you want. However, the 10,000 number seems very peculiar to me. Also, Excel won't listen to you regarding data types! It does whatever it wants. (If you can't tell, I am not a fan of Excel as either a source or a destination).

Comment: If Excel has to be the destination. I kind of prefer SSRS. Formatting seems to stick better with that tool.

Comment: Hi All, Thanks for your contributions. I noticed that it was a bit of sloppiness on my part. Firstly, the reason why the package hangs is because I wrongly configured a send mail script task on Error which wasn't configured properly. Secondly, the actually error is to do with one of the columns being larger than the allowable 255 size that Excel can handle. I just configured ignore on truncation for the particular column.